# Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'vagout' in railway database

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

[model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLMkB.png)I have an error 1022.

Please help me to find a decision.
SQL Code:

```
-- Table `db`.`VagOut`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`VagOut` (
      `VagOutRecNum` INT NOT NULL,
      `VagNum` INT NULL,
      `CargoName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `TrNumOutRec` INT NULL,
      `Netto` INT NULL,
      `Brutto` INT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`VagOutRecNum`),
      INDEX `VagNum_idx` (`VagNum` ASC),
      INDEX `CargoNam_idx` (`CargoName` ASC),
      INDEX `TrNumOutRec_idx` (`TrNumOutRec` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `VagNum`
        FOREIGN KEY (`VagNum`)
        REFERENCES `db`.`Vagon` (`VagNum`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `CargoNam`
        FOREIGN KEY (`CargoName`)
        REFERENCES `db`.`Cargos` (`CargoName`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `TrNumOutRec`
        FOREIGN KEY (`TrNumOutRec`)
        REFERENCES `db`.`TrainOut` (`TrNumOutRec`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

thank u so much

I checked other tables for similar names of fk, but nothing found

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: There are lots of reasons for this error. It's impossible to tell which problem you're having by looking at just one table definition.

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan It's in the title.

Comment: If you search for the error code in SO you'll find many of these reasons. Just keep going through them until you find one that solves your problem.

Comment: Oh ok . Let me see.

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan i have found the previous one, but have no idea about this one

Comment: Are you sure that primary key value is not being duplicated ?

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan there are several names which are similar to primary keys, but none of them are primary keys

Comment: Your error looks like value in column specified as primary key is being duplicated. Can you please check that ?

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLMkB.png here's a link on the image of a model, u can check it :) I can't see anything which matches  your opinion

Comment: Let's say i have name column in the table as primary key, i already have a value 'saranya' in it. And when I reenter the same value in it, i will get the duplicate key error. Is that your case ?

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan idk, probably. i can't find out when it happens

Comment: Try renaming your constraints to values that are not the same as your columns

Comment: @SEarle1986 thank you, it worked